# How can I set the sound channel (output device) permanently?

Tags: sound, settings

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

I clicked on my HDMI sound channel here.

[image: choose a device for output menu]

I press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Volume +</kbd> or <kbd>Volume -</kbd> and this works fine.

But if I reboot and then go to watch a video sound is on 100% and it's night! So I press <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Volume -</kbd>. But, volume the same although it appears to go down.

I go back to the settings, and I click again on HDMI and all works fine again.

So, how can I set up a default sound channel and/or disable sound channels I never use so that I don't have to keep changing my settings after every boot?

Comment: Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your post to narrow this down to a single question. As this is not a forum, rhetorical questions aren't really a good fit here and asking a single question at a time is more likely to provide the desired results. Thank you for helping us help you! You might find [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) useful.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `pactl list sinks`, the content of `~/.pulse/default.pa` (or, lacking that, `/etc/pulse/default.pa`)? Thanks.

Comment: If you care little about save volume settings etc. you can try to delete the current PulseAudio settings and restart its daemon: `pulseaudio -k; rm -r ~/.pulse && puleseaudio --start`.